# tailwind grid responsiveness on small devices not working

Tags: css, next.js, grid, tailwind-css

I am struggling to make a tailwind grid work on breakpoints. I made a card in Nextjs, which I would like to display in the grid format. It looks ok on large devices, but doesn't change when on medium/small devices. the grid should start with 4 columns, then should go to 2 on md devices, and 1 column on small devices. But it doesn't.
I went through the tailwind documentation for the grid, and also looked at few examples so I pretty much understand what needs to be done, but it just doesn't work for me still.

This is the Hero section that is suppose to display this grid:

```
const Hero = () => {
  return (
    <section>
      <div className='flex flex-row justify-between max-w-screen-xl items-center mx-auto p-4'>
        <div className='w-1/2 pt-0'>
          <Image src={Couple_Coder} alt="CodeCouple" className='h-auto'>
          </Image>
        </div>
        <div className='w-1/2 flex flex-col space-y-4 items-center self-center'>
          <div className='h-1/4'>
            <AnimatedText text="Some Text" className='!text-left !text-6xl'/>
            <AnimatedText text="Some Text" className='!text-left !text-6xl'/>
            <AnimatedText text="Some Text" className='!text-left !text-6xl'/>
          </div>
          <div className='mt-10 h-1/4'>
            <p className='my-4 text-base text-center font-medium pb-10'>
              Some Text!!!
            </p>
          </div>  
          <div className='h-1/4 flex flex-row space-x-4 mt-10 mb-8 pt-4 gap-3'>
            <button type='button' className='button-6'>Workshops</button>
            <button type='button' className='button-6 ml-4'>Discord</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className='grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-4 max-w-screen-xl gap-4 mx-auto'>
            <div className='col-span-1'>
                <AnimatedText text="Join Our Workshops" />
            </div>
            <div className='flex col-span-1 md:col-span-2  lg:col-span-4 md:justify-between lg:justify-between gap-4'>
                <Card />        
                <Card />
                <Card />
                <Card />
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
  )
}
```

I also have a layout that applies to all children:

```
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <div className="overflow-hidden bg-site bg-cover bg-no-repeat bg-white border-gray-200 dark:bg-gray-100">
        </div>
        <Navbar />    
        <main className='app xl:p-24 lg:p-16 md:p-12 sm:p-8 bg-white border-gray-200 dark:bg-gray-100 '>
        
        {children}
      </main>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Any who can see what I am doing wrong?
What I want to achieve, is to have 4 columns on lg devices, then 2 colums on md, then 1 column on sm devices.

Thanks

I tried different things in the className of the divs. I also tried changing the screen defaults in tailwind config, and setup my own order going from lg devices first down to sm. but that also didn't work.

Comment: Usually, the smaller breakpoint in tailwind is sm (what signifies small), but it is still "min-width" 640px.

You need to define smaller breakpoints, here is doc: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/screens#adding-smaller-breakpoints

Answer (score 0):

```
<div className='flex col-span-1 md:col-span-2  lg:col-span-4 md:justify-between lg:justify-between gap-4'>
     <Card />        
     <Card />
     <Card />
     <Card />
</div>
```

In This Code section, change the `flex` to `grid`